# update content dynamically in flutter page view

Tags: flutter

I need to update my page view, the data will come from the database(Firestore). refresh the page view and bring the data 
actually, I need to develop an app in which users will post an image and description and other users will be able to view those...

```
List<Widget> stories = [Story_Template(),Story_Page(),Story_Template()]; // ignore: camel_case_types class
Story_Newsfeed_State extends State<Story_Newsfeed> { 
    @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
        // TODO: implement build 
        return Scaffold( 
            body: PageView.builder( 
                itemBuilder : (context,position) => stories[position], 
                itemCount: stories.length, 
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, 
            )); 

    } 
}
```

Comment: List<Widget> stories = [Story_Template(),Story_Page(),Story_Template()];
// ignore: camel_case_types
class Story_Newsfeed_State extends State<Story_Newsfeed> {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        body: PageView.builder(
            itemBuilder : (context,position) => stories[position],
            itemCount: stories.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    )
    );
  }
}

Comment: you can use `FeatureBuilder` widget to get data and build `PageView`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a similar motivational wallpaper [App](https://github.com/shyjuzz/flutter-samples/tree/master/dailyquotes) in flutter using the `flutter_staggered_grid_view` instead of the `pageview`

You may please refer the project. Hope it helps

Source code [GitHub](https://github.com/shyjuzz/flutter-samples/blob/master/dailyquotes/lib/quote_screen.dart)